# What would be a more elegant way to write a low level async connection function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, code-organization

I have a player connect to a channel and upon a successful connection it gets the state from the channel.

```js
this.clientConnectedCallbacks.add(uid, (state) => {
  if (this.clientConnectedCallbacks.has(uid)) {
    this.clientConnectedCallbacks.remove(uid);
    clearTimeout(this.clientConnectedTimeouts.get(uid));
    this.clientConnectedTimeouts.remove(uid);
    return state;
  }
  throw new Error('Client connection callback was no longer in the map.')
});

this.clientConnectedTimeouts.add(uid, setTimeout(() => {
  this.clientConnectedCallbacks.remove(uid);
  this.clientConnectedTimeouts.remove(uid);
  throw new Error(`Client ${uid} connection request to ${this.channelId} timed out`);
}, this.clientTimeout));
```

I leverage the await/async whenever I could and the function this is inside, has the async tag, but this is a very low level implementation and I need to manually make the function return asynchronously. I was wondering if there's any more elegant ideas/design out there to structure something like this?

I want to return the state from the connected channel asynchronously to the client after we receive a successful connection message from the channel (this happens in a completely different function that is made specifically for message handling but has access to the this.clientConnectedCallbacks object

but I also want to time out the client connection in case something goes wrong the promise isnt hanging forever.

Comment: would you mind to explain better what your goal would be please?

Comment: I want to return the state from the connected channel asynchronously to the client after we receive a successful connection message from the channel (this happens in a completely different function that is made specifically for message handling but has access to the this.clientConnectedCallbacks object

but I also want to time out the client connection in case something goes wrong the promise isnt hanging forever.